# Does "fill your hand" count as "draw" in Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

In other words, would [Megafin](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Megafin) trigger [Daring Reporter](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Daring_Reporter)?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The comments and revisions  on the answer show that many people don't know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fill your hand, yes. Megafin, no. Megafin is not drawing but adding cards to your hand. Filling your hand is drawing till your hand is full. Any type of card draw (even if it doesn't say card draw), counts as card draw.

Comment: Are you sure?  By that logic Fire Fly and other token-card generators would trigger Daring Reporter.  That doesn't seem correct.

Comment: The key term is draw. Fire Fly adds cards to your hand that are coming from nowhere. Fill your hand is filling your hand with cards from your deck (not being spawned in).

Comment: Megafin adds cards to your hand from nowhere.  They are random murlocs and NOT from your deck.

Comment: Just changed my post I realized I mixed up Megafin, thank you Lyrl

Comment: That is phrased confusingly, since Megafins text reads: "Fill your hand with random Murlocs". When does "fill your hand" count as a draw, then?

Comment: @Ludi asked myself the same thing. Megafin is the only card that ready "fill your hand"

Comment: Somewhat related: "Copy 2 cards from your opponent's deck" (thoughtsteal) does not trigger daring reporter. Just verified in ranked.

Comment: @Ludi: To disambiguate James' answer: `Filling your hand is drawing till your hand is full.` Quite the opposite. Filling your hand means adding to the hand until you're holding 10 cards (the max amount). Drawing means **taking a card from the deck**. As opposed to _drawn_ cards, generated cards do not get taken from the deck and therefore do not count as a draw. "Filling" does not inherently mean "drawing".

Comment: @Flater  did you miss a „not“?